# React - pass dynamic value to child

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

I have an app that uploads files via a standard `<input type="file"/>`. I'm trying to pass the file size of the chosen file(s) to the child to see if it's above a certain size, and if so, display an error. I know you have to pass state values down as props, but I'm unsure as to where/how to call the function to get an updated value. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I am using the react jsonschema form to build the form: https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form. Declaring the schemas before the Parent class.

Parent

```
const schema = {
    type: 'object',
    required: ['file'],
    properties: {
        file: { type: 'string', format: 'data-url', title: 'File' }
    }
}

const FileWidget = (props) => {
    return (
        <input type="file" id="fileName" required={props.required} onChange={(event) =>  props.onChange(event.target.value)} />
    )
}

const uiSchema = {
    file: {
        'ui:widget': FileWidget,
        classNames: "uiSchema"
    }
}


class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { fileSize: 0 };
        this.getFileSize = this.getFileSize.bind(this);

     getFileSize(){
        this.setState({fileSize: document.getElementById("fileName").files[0].size});
        console.log("FILESIZE:: ", this.state.fileSize);
     } //where to call to update the file size?

     render() {

        return (
           <div className="container">
             <FileUpload schema={schema} uiSchema={uiSchema} fileSize={this.state.fileSize} />
           </div>
        )
     }
}

export default Parent;
```

Child

```
class Child extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { formData: {} };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Form
                schema={this.props.schema}
                uiSchema={this.props.uiSchema}
                formData={this.state.formData}
                onChange={({ formData }) => this.setState({ formData })}
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            >
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-info">Convert</button>
                </div>
            </Form>               
            <div hidden={this.props.fileSize > 100 ? false : true }><h4>File size exceeded.</h4></div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. Passed the function to the child:

```
<FileUpload fileSize={this.getFileSize.bind(this)} />
```

Then in the child added a `setState` to the form's onChange to call the function:

```
onChange={({ formData }) => { this.setState({ formData }); this.setState({fileSize:this.props.fileSize()})}}
```

and displayed the error message accordingly:

```
<div style={{display: this.state.fileSize > 100 ?  "block": "none" }><h4>File size exceeded.</h4></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Parent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { fileSize: 0 };
            this.getFileSize = this.getFileSize.bind(this);

         getFileSize(){
            this.setState({fileSize: document.getElementById("fileName").files[0].size});
            console.log("FILESIZE:: ", this.state.fileSize);
         } //where to call to update the file size?

    componentDidMount(){
     // you can call the getFilesize here        
     this.getFileSize();
    }

         render() {

            return (
               <div className="container">
                 <FileUpload fileSize={this.state.fileSize} />
               </div>
            )
         }
    }

    export default Parent;
```

child Component

```
class FileUpload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { formData: {} };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Form
                    formData={this.state.formData}
                    onChange={({ formData }) => this.setState({ formData })}
                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                >
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-info">Convert</button>
                    </div>
                </Form>               
                <div style={{display:this.props.fileSize > 100 ?  "block": "none" }><h4>File size exceeded.</h4></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    }

    export default FileUpload;
```

I think you want to show the error message when file size exceeds given size

you can also use `componentWillMount` to call `getfilesize`
 it actually depends `document.getElementById("fileName")`
it that particular element  has populated the data by the time your parent componentWill Mount you can use `componentWillMount` lifecycle hook

Comment: That is correct. However, if I call the function in componentDidMount, it will only be called once when the component is first rendered. I need it to call it each time the user selects a new file within the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Parent Component

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  onFileSelected(e) {

    var fileSize = e.target.files.length > 0 ? e.target.files[0].size : false;
    if (fileSize)
      this.setState({ fileSize });

  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileSelected.bind(this)} />
        <FileUpload fileSize={this.state.fileSize}></FileUpload>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

child Component

```
class FileUpload extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.fileSize > 100 ? <h2 >File size exceeds 100</h2> : null}
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

in the above code what i did is created `<input type="file"/>` in parent component and attached a onchange event to it.